# How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?

Tags: python, floating-point

Here's my code:

```
x = 1.0
y = 100000.0    
print x/y
```

My quotient displays as `1.00000e-05`.

Is there any way to suppress scientific notation and make it display as
`0.00001`? I'm going to use the result as a string.

Comment: It is disappointing that none of the answers here address the question. It would be nice if there was a way to prevent python(3) from using scientific notation at all except when specified explicitly. All of the answers require the user to explicitly suppress scientific notation, which is not the same as generally suppressing the implicit use of scientific notation from within python.

Comment: yes, like R does with `options(scipen = 999)`

Comment: @BLUC the `numpy` module offers `np.format_float_positional()` and this works well.

Comment: Not worth an answer on it's own, but I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67879685/python-decimal-decimal-producing-result-in-scientific-notation is better than any existing answer here if combined with `.replace(",", "")`.

Comment: Python is so insane, I cannot stop being amazed by its intrinsic stupidity and lack of practicality comparing to literally any other modern language. Such a bummer this abomination became so popular.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
'%f' % (x/y)
```

but you need to manage precision yourself. e.g.,

```
'%f' % (1/10**8)
```

will display zeros only.
[details are in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Or for Python 3 [the equivalent old formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations) or the [newer style formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Comment: I suggest clarifying your statement to say, "you manage the *display* of precision yourself."  The actual (Python internal) precision isn't changed, as is often done in other languages.

Answer (score 181):

Using the newer version `''.format` (also remember to specify how many digit after the `.` you wish to display, this depends on how small is the floating number). See this example:

```
>>> a = -7.1855143557448603e-17
>>> '{:f}'.format(a)
'-0.000000'
```

as shown above, default is 6 digits! This is not helpful for our case example, so instead we could use something like this:

```
>>> '{:.20f}'.format(a)
'-0.00000000000000007186'
```

### Update

Starting in Python 3.6, this can be simplified with the new [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), as follows:

```
>>> f'{a:.20f}'
'-0.00000000000000007186'
```

Comment: How to do this while specifying significant figures though?

Comment: I guess by using a variable, give it the desired number of digits, and use it instead of the literal number e.g. `f"{a:.{precision}f}"`

Comment: how are you supposed to know what value to use for `precision`?

Comment: It does not work for me `time.time() #shortStuff  end = time.time() print( '{:.20}'.format(end - start),"sec")`

Comment: @Xanlantos Read the answer again. It's not `{:.20}` as in your code but `{:.20f}`.

Comment: Oh gosh that was long ago ^^, but ur absolutely right

Answer (score 57):

Another option, if you are using pandas and would like to suppress scientific notation for all floats, is to adjust the pandas options.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

Comment: I found this answer useful specially combining it with the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830393/5127304) for further endorsement:
`import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`

Answer (score 56):

With newer versions of Python (2.6 and later), you can use [`''.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to accomplish what @SilentGhost suggested:

```
'{0:f}'.format(x/y)
```

And since [PEP-498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) is over 8 years old, Python 3.6 and later supports:

```
f'{x/y:f}'
```

Someone commented on printing lists, so here's a bonus 1-liner:

```
[f'{x:f}' for x in long_list]
```

Comment: Is this really what you want? I don't:

```>>> print('{:f}'.format(0.000000123))```

```0.000000```

Comment: @duality you might need to specify precision. `'{0:.10f}'`

Comment: Also doesn't work if you're trying to print a list of values. We need a global format setting.

Answer (score 55):

Most of the answers above require you to specify precision. But what if you want to display floats like this, with no unnecessary zeros:

```
1
0.1
0.01
0.001
0.0001
0.00001
0.000001
0.000000000001
```

`numpy` has an answer: [`np.format_float_positional`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html)

```
import numpy as np

def format_float(num):
    return np.format_float_positional(num, trim='-')
```

Comment: this is **the best answer if you want a general number of decimal places** (ie. do not need to specify decimal places before).

Answer (score 21):

In case of numpy arrays you can suppress with suppress command as

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the built-in `format` function.

```
>>> a = -3.42142141234123e-15
>>> format(a, 'f')
'-0.000000'
>>> format(a, '.50f') # Or you can specify precision
'-0.00000000000000342142141234122994048466990874926279'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this adds garbage numbers at the end of nice round floats like: `format(0.001, '.50f') = '0.00100000000000000002081668171172168513294309377670'`

Answer (score 6):

This will work for any exponent:

```
def getExpandedScientificNotation(flt):
    str_vals = str(flt).split('e')
    coef = float(str_vals[0])
    exp = int(str_vals[1])
    return_val = ''
    if int(exp) > 0:
        return_val += str(coef).replace('.', '')
        return_val += ''.join(['0' for _ in range(0, abs(exp - len(str(coef).split('.')[1])))])
    elif int(exp) < 0:
        return_val += '0.'
        return_val += ''.join(['0' for _ in range(0, abs(exp) - 1)])
        return_val += str(coef).replace('.', '')
    return return_val
```

Answer (score 4):

This is using [Captain Cucumber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604186/8282282), but with 2 additions.

1) allowing the function to get non scientific notation numbers and just return them as is (so you can throw a lot of input that some of the numbers are 0.00003123 vs  3.123e-05 and still have function work.

2) added support for negative numbers. (in original function,  a negative number would end up like 0.0000-108904 from -1.08904e-05)

```
def getExpandedScientificNotation(flt):
    was_neg = False
    if not ("e" in flt):
        return flt
    if flt.startswith('-'):
        flt = flt[1:]
        was_neg = True 
    str_vals = str(flt).split('e')
    coef = float(str_vals[0])
    exp = int(str_vals[1])
    return_val = ''
    if int(exp) > 0:
        return_val += str(coef).replace('.', '')
        return_val += ''.join(['0' for _ in range(0, abs(exp - len(str(coef).split('.')[1])))])
    elif int(exp) < 0:
        return_val += '0.'
        return_val += ''.join(['0' for _ in range(0, abs(exp) - 1)])
        return_val += str(coef).replace('.', '')
    if was_neg:
        return_val='-'+return_val
    return return_val
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the top result on Google, I will post here after failing to find a solution for my problem. **If you are looking to format the display value of a float object and have it remain a float - not a string, you can use this solution:**

Create a new class that modifies the way that float values are displayed.

```
from builtins import float
class FormattedFloat(float):

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:.10f}".format(self).rstrip('0')
```

You can modify the precision yourself by changing the integer values in `{:f}`

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers work but have a flaw: the number of decimal digits will change (either be increased or trimmed)

Here is a solution that will work and will not change the precision of your number.

```
from decimal import Decimal
number = Decimal('0.000000001')
# f-string
f'{number:.{abs(number.as_tuple().exponent)}f}'
# or format
format(number, '.{0}f'.format(abs(number.as_tuple().exponent)))
```

You can make a class such as

```
class FormatedDecimal(Decimal):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self:.{abs(self.as_tuple().exponent)}f}'
```

And will give you:

```
>>> str(FormatedDecimal(100000))
'100000'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('10000.0'))
'10000.0'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('0.0000000001'))
'0.0000000001'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('1.00000000000000000001'))
'1.00000000000000000001'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('0.0000000000000'))
'0.0000000000000'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('0.0000000000000'))
'0.0000000000000'
>>> str(FormatedDecimal('1.48e-9'))
'0.00000000148'
```

Comment: ```
>>> this = float(0.000002) # as my calculations will return a Float
>>> str(FormatedDecimal(this))
'0.00000199999999999999990949622365177251737122787744738161563873291015625'
```

How to avoid that Decimal is changing the value of the Float ?

Comment: The problem is "this" is a float. Floating point numbers are note able represent every number, (i.e; 0.000002 cannot not be represented as a float) for this reason https://0.30000000000000004.com/ .
If you want to not loose precision, you should use a decimal instead of a float (https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).
If you try this, it will work:

this = Decimal('0.000002')
str(FormatedDecimal(this))

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `string` then use the built in `float` on it to do the conversion for instance:
`print( "%.5f" % float("1.43572e-03"))`
answer:`0.00143572`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution to display a float to an arbitrary number of significant digits. No `numpy` or list comprehensions required here:

```
def sig(num, digits=3):
    "Return number formatted for significant digits"
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    negative = '-' if num < 0 else ''
    num = abs(float(num))
    power = math.log(num, 10)
    if num < 1:
        step = int(10**(-int(power) + digits) * num)
        return negative + '0.' + '0' * -int(power) + str(int(step)).rstrip('0')
    elif power < digits - 1:
        return negative + ('{0:.' + str(digits) + 'g}').format(num)
    else:
        return negative + str(int(num))
```

I'm stripping trailing 0s and displaying full integers in the example: `sig(31415.9) = 31415` instead of 31400. Feel free to modify the code if that's not something you're into.

Testing:

```
for power in range(-8,8):
    num = math.pi * 10**power
    print(str(num).ljust(25), sig(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SG's answer, you can also use the Decimal module:

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = str(Decimal(1) / Decimal(10000))

# x is a string '0.0001'
```

Comment: it turns to scientific notation for values smaller than 1e-6

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.6.4, I was having a similar problem that randomly, a number in the output file would be formatted with scientific notation when using this:

```
fout.write('someFloats: {0:0.8},{1:0.8},{2:0.8}'.format(someFloat[0], someFloat[1], someFloat[2]))
```

All that I had to do to fix it was to add 'f':

```
fout.write('someFloats: {0:0.8f},{1:0.8f},{2:0.8f}'.format(someFloat[0], someFloat[1], someFloat[2]))
```

Answer (score -1):

As of 3.6 (probably works with slightly older 3.x as well), this is my solution:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

def number_format(n, dec_precision=4):
    precision = len(str(round(n))) + dec_precision
    return format(float(n), f'.{precision}n')
```

The purpose of the `precision` calculation is to ensure we have enough precision to keep out of scientific notation (default precision is still 6).

The `dec_precision` argument adds additional precision to use for decimal points. Since this makes use of the `n` format, no insignificant zeros will be added (unlike `f` formats). `n` also will take care of rendering already-round integers without a decimal.

`n` does require `float` input, thus the cast.

Answer (score -4):

I was having a similar problem that randomly, using my solution:

```
from decimal import Decimal

Decimal(2/25500)
#output:0.00007843137254901961000728982664753630160703323781490325927734375
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Tried dividing -1/-2147483648