# How to avoid printing scientific notation in python without adding extra digits?

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python) asks how to suppress scientific notation in python.

I have a series of numbers to display -- small powers of 10 -- and I'd like to display them without trailing zeros. I.e. 0.1, 0.01, and so on to 0.000001

If I do `"%s" % 10 ** -6` I get `'1e-06'`. If I use `"%f" % 10 ** -6` I get `'0.000001'` which is what I want.

However, `"%f" % 10 ** -3` yields `'0.001000'` which violates the "without trailing zeros" constraint.

It's not hard to brute force a way around this (regex replacement or something), but I'm wondering if there's some format string magic I'm missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me a little hacky, but you can use `str.rstrip("0")` to get rid of trailing zeros:

```
>>> "{:f}".format(10**-6).rstrip("0")
'0.000001'
>>> "{:f}".format(10**-3).rstrip("0")
'0.001'
```

Edit: As said in comments, there is a better way for this:

```
>>> format(1e-6, 'f').rstrip('0')
'0.000001'
>>> format(1e-3, 'f').rstrip('0')
'0.001'
```

Comment: That's what the OP referred to as *"brute force a way around this"*, so it's not a real answer (-1). However, I'd do it this way too (+1).

Comment: +1. It's not hacky at all. Maybe using the `format()` function is a tiny bit cleaner: `format(1e-6, 'f').rstrip('0')`.

Comment: @Oben Sonne, but its far better than using regex. @Ferdinand Beyer, thanks, I didn't know that, modifying answer.

Comment: This isn't that bad; I had forgotten that `rstrip` takes an arg for the character to remove.

Comment: @utdemir, absolutely, that's why I would do it the same way. Nevertheless it's not really format string magic, as asked for by the OP.

Comment: The longer version of utdemirs answer: There is no format string option for this. You will have to write a solution by yourself.  This is not so bad, because the solution is quite simple, as demonstrated by utdemirs use of the `rstrip` method.

Answer (score 2):

The simple `rstrip("0")` does not handle small and certain other values well, it should leave one zero after the decimal point - `0.0` instead of `0.`:

```
def format_float(value, precision=-1):
    if precision < 0:
        f = "%f" % value
    else:
        f = "%.*f" % (precision, value)

    p = f.partition(".")

    s = "".join((p[0], p[1], p[2][0], p[2][1:].rstrip("0")))

    return s

print(format_float(3e-10))
print(format_float(3e-10, 20))
print(format_float(1.5e-6))
print(format_float(1.5e+6))
```