# Python float to string, only "dotted notation"?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, representation

I'm writing floating point numbers to a text file and I'd really appreciate if Python would stop writing numbers like "0.000002" as "2e-6". What can I do?

Comment: What does your text output code look like?

Comment: duplicate of this question, has a few good answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use formatting directives, such as this one:

```
n = 0.000002
print('{:f}'.format(n))
0.000002
```

more information about formatting see these [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec)

Or old-style if working pre Python v2.6 (thanks @mgilson and @artSwri)

```
print('%f' % n)
```

Comment: This raises a ValueError on python 2.6 (OS-X)  (ValueError: zero length field name in format)

Comment: @ArtSwri -- I'm using python 2.6.  (which meets the requirements)

Comment: @mgilson: Does it work for you if you replace `'{:f}'` with `'{0:f}'`?

Comment: @EdwardLoper -- Yes it does.  (one of these days I'm going to get around to learning `.format` in place of `%`) -- I suppose maybe this is the beginning of my education ...

Comment: @mgilson I noticed some inconsistencies with v 2.6.5 under Ubuntu compared to 2.7.3 and 3.2.3 under Windows just this morning. 2.6.5 required more specification information, but worked

Comment: @Levon -- I assumed there would be a way to coax it to work -- I just figured that I'd ask in order to document the differences between python versions in the comments here (at very least)

Comment: @mgilson I'm with you (just started yesterday to dig up info on .format .. long time C user I'm very comfy with the whole % thingy)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "%f" % 2e-6
'0.000002'
```

Comment: @mgilson See the link in KDiTraglia's comment for why 2e-7 "doesn't work" and how you can fix it.