# How to avoid e-05 in python

Tags: python, int, decimal

I have a Python program where i calculate some probabilities, but in some of the answers I get f.ex. 8208e-06, but I want my numbers to come out on the regular form 0.000008... How do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean come out - are you printing them and the format is unexpected?

Comment: Well, yeah. The format is as described 8208e-06, but I need to be written in the "normal form". Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I suppress scientific notation in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `f` format specifier and specify the number of decimal digits:

```
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(1e-10)
'0.0000000001'
```

Precision defaults to `6`, so:

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(1e-6)
'0.000001'
>>> '{:f}'.format(1e-7)
'0.000000'
```

---

If you want to remove trailing zeros just [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) them:

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(1.1)
'1.100000'
>>> '{:f}'.format(1.1).rstrip('0')
'1.1'
```

---

By default when converting to string using `str` (or `repr`) python returns the shortest possible representation for the given float, which may be the exponential notation.

This is usually what you want, because the decimal representation may display the representation error which user of applications usually don't want and don't care to see:

```
>>> '{:.16f}'.format(1.1)
'1.1000000000000001'
>>> 1.1
1.1
```