# Preventing engineering notation in Python's decimal

Tags: python, decimal

I use decimal objects whose values get close to zero. By default, a statement such as

```
print (decimal.Decimal('0.00000000004') / decimal.Decimal('2'))
```

will output `2E-11`. How do I prevent this from happening and get `0.00000000002` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I suppress scientific notation in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python)

Comment: `'{0:f}'.format(decimal.Decimal('0.00000000004') / decimal.Decimal('2'))`

Answer (score 1):

To get the decimal point You need to format the print

```
print "{:.11f}".format(decimal.Decimal('0.00000000004') / decimal.Decimal('2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = decimal.Decimal('0.00000000004') / decimal.Decimal('2')
print '{:.50f}'.format(num)
print '{:.2f}'.format(num)
```

You can read more in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)