# Python division yielding larger answers than it should?

Tags: python, division

I am trying to make a calculator in Python that gives you the amount of time it would take for light to travel X miles, but I'm having some division problems.

When I input "1" or any small number, it gives me a larger number than it should. For example, I input "5" and it tells me "It would take 2.684096876850903e-05 seconds for light to travel 5.0 miles.", even though it only takes 0.00002684096877 seconds. What's odd is the calculator actually works with large numbers. (For example, I input milesPerSecond and it gives me "1", like it should.)

Is there something I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
variable = 1
while variable == 1:
    input1 = input("How many miles do you want light to travel? ");
    miles = float(input1);
    milesPerSecond = 186282.397;
    seconds = miles / milesPerSecond;
    if seconds < 60:
        print("It would take", seconds, "seconds for light to travel", miles, "miles.");
    elif seconds < 3600:
        print("It would take", seconds / 60, "minutes for light to travel", miles, "miles.");
    elif seconds < 86400:
        print("It would take", seconds / 3600, "hours for light to travel", miles, "miles.");
    elif seconds > 86400:
        print("It would take", seconds / 86400, "days for light to trabel", miles, "miles.");
    print("");
```

Comment: Just note that `2.684096876850903e-05` is equal to `0.00002684096877`

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax to change the how the value looks.

Comment: This question may be off-topic because it was caused by a misinterpretation of the output; the code in question works as intended. Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/658763/2069350).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two answers you show are the same, one is in scientific notation, the other is in standard notation.

For example:

```
0.00000000851  ==  8.51e-9
```