# How to convert double with scientific format to String Using spark Java API?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm new in spark Java API. I want to transform double with scientific format example: 1.7E7---->17000000,00.

MyDataSet is:

```
+---------+------------+
|  account|    amount  |
+---------+------------+
| c1      |      1.7E7 |
| c2      |      1.5E8 |
| c3      |      142.0 |
```

I want to transform my dataset to something like this.

```
    +---------+----------------------+
    |  account|    amount            |
    +---------+----------------------+
    | c1      |      17000000,00     |
    | c2      |      1500000000,00   |
    | c3      |      142,00          |
```

Can someOne guide me with an expression in spark Java to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off scientific notation in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206592/how-to-turn-off-scientific-notation-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it like this. Don't forget import `spark.sql.functions`

```
Dataset<Row> myDataset = ....
myDataset = myDataset.withColumn("newAmount", col("amount").cast(DataTypes.DoubleType))
    .drop(col("amount"))
    .withColumnRenamed("newAmount","amount")
    .toDF();
```

Comment: I resolve my probleme using this: myDataset = myDataset.withColumn("newAmount", col("amount").cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(20, 2)))
    .drop(col("amount"))
    .withColumnRenamed("newAmount","amount")
    .toDF();