# How to load big double numbers in a PySpark DataFrame and persist it back without changing the numeric format to scientific notation or precision?

Tags: dataframe, user-defined-functions, pyspark, scientific-notation

I have a CSV like that:

```
COL,VAL
TEST,100000000.12345679
TEST2,200000000.1234
TEST3,9999.1234679123
```

I want to load it having the column `VAL` as a numeric type (due to other requirements of the project) and then persist it back to another CSV as per structure below:

```
+-----+------------------+
|  COL|               VAL|
+-----+------------------+
| TEST|100000000.12345679|
|TEST2|    200000000.1234|
|TEST3|   9999.1234679123|
+-----+------------------+
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I load it, the numbers become scientific notation, and I cannot persist it back without having to inform the `precision` and `scale` of my data (I want to use the one that it is already in the file, whatever it is - I can't infer it).
Here's what I have tried:

Loading it with `DoubleType()` it gives me scientific notation:

```
schema = StructType([
StructField('COL', StringType()),
StructField('VAL', DoubleType())
])

csv_file = "Downloads/test.csv"
df2 = (spark.read.format("csv")
.option("sep",",")
.option("header", "true")
.schema(schema)
.load(csv_file))

df2.show()

+-----+--------------------+
|  COL|                 VAL|
+-----+--------------------+
| TEST|1.0000000012345679E8|
|TEST2|    2.000000001234E8|
|TEST3|     9999.1234679123|
+-----+--------------------+
```

Loading it with `DecimalType()` I'm required to specify `precision` and `scale`, otherwise, I lose the decimals after the dot. However, specifying it, besides the risk of not getting the correct value (as my data might be rounded), I get zeros after the dot:
For example, using: `StructField('VAL', DecimalType(38, 18))` I get:

```
[Row(COL='TEST', VAL=Decimal('100000000.123456790000000000')),
Row(COL='TEST2', VAL=Decimal('200000000.123400000000000000')),
Row(COL='TEST3', VAL=Decimal('9999.123467912300000000'))]
```

Realise that in this case, I have zeros on the right side that I don't want in my new file.

The only way I found to address it was using a `UDF` where I first use the `float()` to remove the scientific notation and then I convert it to string to make sure it will be persisted as I want:

```
to_decimal = udf(lambda n: str(float(n)))

df2 = df2.select("*", to_decimal("VAL").alias("VAL2"))
df2 = df2.select(["COL", "VAL2"]).withColumnRenamed("VAL2", "VAL")
df2.show()
display(df2.schema)

+-----+------------------+
|  COL|               VAL|
+-----+------------------+
| TEST|100000000.12345679|
|TEST2|    200000000.1234|
|TEST3|   9999.1234679123|
+-----+------------------+

StructType(List(StructField(COL,StringType,true),StructField(VAL,StringType,true)))
```

There's any way to reach the same without using the `UDF` trick?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just found out that I can get closer to what I want with `decimal.Decimal(100000000.123456790000000000).normalize()`, but I didn't find a `normalize()` method in the `DecimalType()`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to address it was as bellow. It is still using `UDF`, but now, without the workarounds with Strings to avoid scientific notation. I won't make it as correct answer yet, because I still expect someone coming over with a solution without UDF (or a good explanation of why it's not possible without `UDF`s).

1. The CSV:

```
$ cat /Users/bambrozi/Downloads/testf.csv
COL,VAL
TEST,100000000.12345679
TEST2,200000000.1234
TEST3,9999.1234679123
TEST4,123456789.01234567
```

2. Load the CSV applying the default PySpark `DecimalType` precision and scale:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('COL', StringType()),
    StructField('VAL', DecimalType(38, 18))
])

csv_file = "Downloads/testf.csv"
df2 = (spark.read.format("csv")
        .option("sep",",")
        .option("header", "true")
        .schema(schema)
        .load(csv_file))

df2.show(truncate=False)
```

output:

```
+-----+----------------------------+
|COL  |VAL                         |
+-----+----------------------------+
|TEST |100000000.123456790000000000|
|TEST2|200000000.123400000000000000|
|TEST3|9999.123467912300000000     |
|TEST4|123456789.012345670000000000|
+-----+----------------------------+
```

3. When you are ready to report it (print or save in a new file) you apply a format to trailing zeros:

```
import decimal
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
normalize_decimals = F.udf(lambda dec: dec.normalize())
(df2
    .withColumn('VAL', normalize_decimals(F.col('VAL')))
    .show(truncate=False))
```

output:

```
+-----+------------------+
|COL  |VAL               |
+-----+------------------+
|TEST |100000000.12345679|
|TEST2|200000000.1234    |
|TEST3|9999.1234679123   |
|TEST4|123456789.01234567|
+-----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to accomplish what you are asking without using a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType, DecimalType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
schema = StructType([
    StructField("COL", StringType(), True),
    StructField("VAL", DoubleType(), True)
])

data = [("TEST", 100000000.12345679),
        ("TEST2", 200000000.1234),
        ("TEST3", 9999.1234679123)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.show()

MAX_PRECISION = 38
MAX_SCALE = 10
df = df.withColumn("VAL", df["VAL"].cast(DecimalType(MAX_PRECISION, MAX_SCALE)).cast("string"))
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("VAL", F.expr("rtrim('0', VAL)"))  # remove trailing zeros
df.show()

# Can now 'df' to file, as you please, without trailing zeros
```

output:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|  COL|                 VAL|
+-----+--------------------+
| TEST|1.0000000012345679E8|
|TEST2|    2.000000001234E8|
|TEST3|     9999.1234679123|
+-----+--------------------+

+-----+--------------------+
|  COL|                 VAL|
+-----+--------------------+
| TEST|100000000.1234567900|
|TEST2|200000000.1234000000|
|TEST3|     9999.1234679123|
+-----+--------------------+

+-----+------------------+
|  COL|               VAL|
+-----+------------------+
| TEST|100000000.12345679|
|TEST2|    200000000.1234|
|TEST3|   9999.1234679123|
+-----+------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use spark to do that with sql query :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
    .setAppName(this.getClass.getName)
    .setMaster("local[*]")

implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").format("csv").load(csv_file)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")

val query = "Select cast(VAL as BigDecimal) as VAL, COL from table"
val result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
result.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").csv(outputPath + table)
```

Comment: Hi @sofiane-belghali, thanks but didn't work. I converted your code to PySpark (Python) and changed the `BigDecimal` to `Decimal` (PySpark don't have the first one) and the result was given as `DecimalType(10,0)`. It removed the decimals after the dot.