# Subtract 2 dataframe columns and get the result without weird rounding (floating point arithmetic)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Pandas dataframes, with thousands of values. I load them from a csv file with Pandas' *read_csv* function.
I need to subtract a column ("open") of the second one from a column of the first, and i do it like this:

```
subtraction = shiftedDataset.open - dataset.open
```

And i get a series with the results.
The problem is the results come with the weird rounding that comes from the floating point arithmetic.
(e.g. a value that should be **0.00003** is **-2.999999999997449e-05**)

How can i get the correct results? I can manipulate the dataframe before the subtraction or the values after the subtraction, i don't care, but i need to get the best performance possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is scientific notation, and is probably more accurate if you want to do more calculations. If this is purely for display purposes, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python)

Example:

```
v = -2.999999999997449e-05
print('%f' % v)
>>> '-0.000030'
```

Some are for formatting the output (tuning your value into a string, might not be what you want), but there's also a pandas setting you can use (also on the same post, scroll down a bit).