# Avoid printing exponential value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to print the actual value instead of exponential value?

```
>>> val=0.00004
>>> print(str(val))
4e-05
```

Comment: Checkout https://pyformat.info it's got a ton of helpful tricks regarding formatting. The section on floats may be of use to you.

Comment: `print(f'{val:f}')`

Comment: You can use simple argument specifier - `%f`. This statement prints value with the precision of 6 digits to the right of the dot: `print("%6f" val) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in here: [How do I suppress scientific notation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python#5463788)

```
print('{0:f}'.format(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
print('{:f}'.format(val))
```