# How to represent the number like '1.108779411784206406864790428E-69', between 0-1 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number that comes from Sigmoid function like '1.108779411784206406864790428E-69' but it's naturally should be between 0-1. How can I represent it in that way? Thanks

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] and explain exactly what your issue is?

Comment: I have float typed 1.108779411784206406864790428E-69 number in Python. And this number comes from a sigmoid function which is always return a number between 0-1, but in my case it's printed like Scientific Notation. I want to change this to a number between 0-1.

Comment: The float is already a number between 0-1; python just prints it in scientific notation.

Comment: So how can I format this number so I can actually see that value is between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python

Comment: You *already can* see that the value is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that you got is the scientific notation of this number: 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011087794117842064068647904281594

To get the number like that, you need to do this:

```
x = 1.108779411784206406864790428E-69
print("%.100f" % x)
```

"%.100f" is the string to format, where 100 is the number of floats you need to show.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format statement to print. The original value is a float. For the convenience of readability python prints in scientific notation since this is a very small number. You can print upto more decimal places.. I have printed upto 96 decimal places below.

```
>>> a=1.108779411784206406864790428E-69
>>> "{:.96f}".format(a)
'0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001108779411784206406864790428'
```

Hope this helps.