# Convert string to float trouble python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a problem. My code:

```
a = '0.00003162'
b = float(a)
print(b)
```

result: `3.162e-05`

I want operating on `0.00003162`.

---

```
list = ['0.00003162', '0.00003161', '0.00003160', '0.00003159', '0.00003158']
list2 = [float(i) for i in list]
```

result: `[3.17e-05, 3.171e-05, 3.172e-05, 3.187e-05, 3.188e-05]`

but i want: `[0.00003162, 0.00003161, 0.00003160, 0.00003159, 0.00003158]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I suppress scientific notation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-do-i-suppress-scientific-notation-in-python)

Comment: You seem to be confusing floats and their string representations. If you want to control the strings used to print them, use formatting. In any event, unless this is for some end user -- why not just accept the defaults? It isn't a bad idea to become comfortable with scientific notation.

Comment: To add to my previous comment `3.162e-05 == 0.00003162` evaluates to `True` so you *are* getting the floats that you want but are just unhappy with the way `print()` prints them by default.