# Python decimal.Decimal producing result in scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, decimal, scientific-notation

I'm dividing a very long into much smaller number. Both are of type decimal.Decimal().

The result is coming out in scientific notation. How do I stop this? I need to print the number in full.

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec
50
>>> val
Decimal('1000000000000000000000000')
>>> units
Decimal('1500000000')
>>> units / val
Decimal('1.5E-15')
```

Comment: Use *formatting*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render the decimal into a formatted string with a float type-indicator `{:,f}`, and it will display just the right number of digits to express the whole number, regardless of whether it is a very large integer or a very large decimal.

```
>>> val
Decimal('1000000000000000000000000')

>>> units
Decimal('1500000000')

>>> "{:,f}".format(units / val)
'0.0000000000000015'

# very large decimal integer, formatted as float-type string, appears without any decimal places at all when it has none! Nice!

>>> "{:,f}".format(units * val)
 '1,500,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000'
```

**You don't need to specify the decimal places**. It will display only as many as required to express the number, omitting that trail of useless zeros that appear after the final decimal digit when the decimal is shorter than a fixed format width. And you don't get any decimal places if the number has no fraction part.

**Very large numbers** are therefore accommodated without having to second guess how large they will be. And you don't have to second guess whether they will be have decimal places either.

**Any specified thousands separator** `{:,f}` will likewise only have effect if it turns out that the number is a large integer instead of a long decimal.

**Proviso**

Decimal(), however, has this idea of ***significant places***, by which it will add trailing zeros if it thinks you want them.

The idea is that it intelligently handles situations where you might be dealing with currency digits such as `£ 10.15`. To use the example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('1.30') +  decimal.Decimal('1.20')
Decimal('2.50')
```

It makes no difference if you format the Decimal() - you still get the trailing zero if the Decimal() deems it to be significant:

```
>>> "{:,f}".format( decimal.Decimal('1.30') +  decimal.Decimal('1.20'))
'2.50'
```

The same thing happens (perhaps for some good reason?) when you treat thousands and fractions together:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(2500) * decimal.Decimal('0.001')
Decimal('2.500')
```

**Remove significant trailing zeros** with the Decimal().normalize() method:

```
>>> (2500 * decimal.Decimal('0.001')).normalize()
Decimal('2.5')
```

Answer (score 2):

The precision is kept internally - you just have to explicitly call for the number of decimal places you want at the point you are exporting your decimal value to a string.

So, if you are going a print, or inserting the value in an HTML template, the first step is to use the string format method (or f-strings), to ensure the number is encompassed:

```
In [29]: print(f"{units/val:.50f}")                                                                                                                    
0.00000000000000150000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Unfortunatelly, the [string-format minilanguage](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers) has no way to eliminate by itself the redundant zeroes on the right hand side. (the left side can be padded with "0", " ", custom characters, whatever one want, but all the precision after the decimal separator is converted to trailing 0s).

Since finding the least significant non-zero digit is complicated - otherwiser we could use a parameter extracted from the number instead of the "50" for precision in the format expression, the simpler thing is to remove those zeros after formatting take place, with the string `.rstrip` method:

```py
In [30]: print(f"{units/val:.50f}".rstrip("0"))                                                                                                        
0.0000000000000015
```

In short: this seems to be the only way to go: in all interface points, where the number is leaving the core to an output where it is representd as a string, you format it with an excess of precision with the fixed point notation, and strip out the tailing zeros with f-string:

```
return template.render(number=f"{number:.50f}".rstrip("0"), ...)
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course.  And best of all - you don't actually need to specify the decimal places at all:    `print("{:,f}".format(units / val)
    '0.0000000000000015'`
That way you don't get a trail of useless zeros after the final decimal digit when the decimal is shorter than your format width - and very large numbers are therefore accommodated without having to second guess how large they will be. Thank you for correcting my late night fog.