# Convert decimal string to integer and include the zeros

Tags: python

I have an output that is a string, such as: price: "0.00007784"

I'd like to convert that string to a number so as I can perform arithmetic on it (add 10% to it, for example). However, I try:
`convertedPrice = int(float(number))` and I get 0 as the result.
I need the whole string converted to a number, as it is and **not** in scientific form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you converting it to an integer when it's a tiny fraction?

Comment: `int` means `integer`, as in whole number, so it will 'throw away' everything after the decimal place. In terms of scientific notation, operate on it as a `float` then use string formatting to display it when you finally output results.

Comment: Just use `float()` not `int()`

Comment: 0.00007784 is pretty low cost...

Comment: In your own words, what is an integer? Can `0.00007784` be represented as an integer? In your own words, where you have `int(float(number))`, what do you think the `float` part means? What do you think the `int` part means?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears not to be a question about programming, but a question about definitions. It only makes sense to ask this question if someone thinks that "integer" and "number" mean the same thing, which they do not.

Comment: Scientific notation is an input/output format, it's not part of the value of the number. You can use formatting operators to control whether this format is used.

Comment: As mentioned, the scientific notation is just a matter of ***representing*** the number, not how it is saved in memory. So while `print(float("0.00007784"))` will give `7.784e-05`, you can control for example by doing `print(format(float("0.00007784"), 'f'))` which will give `0.000078`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/658763/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the string is converted to a whole number is because you use the int function to convert it to an integer.

When you print the float value you may get the scientific notation, but that does not mean it is stored in scientific notation, this is only the way it represented when converted back to a string. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values) question’s answer explain how this can be avoided.

An alternative would be to use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) if you want it to be very specifically stored in decimal notation, and the cost of increased computation.

Comment: In fact, a floating-point number is always stored in scientific notation (though with a power of 2).