# How do you stop Python from converting a number to scientific notation?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
m = int(input(""))
p= 3.00*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10
c = p*p
E = m * c

print(E)
```

The answer is `19e+16`.

But I don't want the scientific notation: I want the number.

Comment: If you change `3.00` to `3` then your number will be an int.

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't unique or controllable from vscode. Also, `3 * 10**8` looks cleaner

Comment: Thanks now it works

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is not from VSCode, Python prints that way for better readability. You can print the long form with the help of string formatting. When you apply precision it will expand the printed value:

```py
E = 3.00 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100 * 100
print(E)
print(f"{E:.1f}")
print(f"{E:.10f}")
```

output:

```
3e+16
30000000000000000.0
30000000000000000.0000000000
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: 
[How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values)
TL;DR

```
print('{:f}'.format(E))
```