# How can scientific notation be removed for viewing [pca.explained_variance_ratio_]?

Tags: python, arrays, pca

How to remove the scientific notation for viewing  [pca.explained_variance_ratio_] ? to any number of desired decimal places
[[resulting array with notation]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm4Pq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```