# Decimal - remove trailing zeros and supress scientifict notation

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I need a function which works like format_float_postional, but doesn't round. It is function which:

- should remove trailing zeros
- doesn't round (problem with that)
- should supress scientifict notation
- can be used with Decimal

This is the closesest soultion I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106536/3565923

```
import numpy as np
formated = np.format_float_positional((float(instance.factor)), trim="-")
```

Intance factor is a field in serializer. It is Decimal!

```
class NewConversionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    factor = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=20)
```

At the moment I get:
`0.55555555555555555550 -> 0.5555555555555556`
I'd want it to be: `0.5555555555555555555`

It would be great if both output and input would be decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 = decimal.Decimal("0.555555555555555555555555550")
d2 = decimal.Decimal("0.555555555555555555555555550e-10")
"{:.1000f}".format(d1).rstrip('0')
"{:.1000f}".format(d2).rstrip('0')
```

Output:

```
'0.55555555555555555555555555'
'0.000000000055555555555555555555555555'
```

It works (Python 3.8.10), but it needs a lot more testing in my opinion...

Comment: Why not just use `"{:f}"` instead of `"{:.1000f}"`? (Or even better, `format(d1, "f")` or `f"{d1:f}"`.)

Comment: Default precision for `{":f"}` is 6

Comment: precision is 6 for floats, but for Decimal it seems to work as expected