# How to remove the Scientific notation E getting stored in CSV using Python without pandas?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to get details from DB and store in CSV, but when i open the csv I see the rows for Id reflecting as below:
Id
4.98518E+11

How to remove the E+ from csv wihtout using Pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values)

Comment: no it is adding 0 at end and not giving original values @luk2302

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the *default `str()` formatting* of floating point numbers, where scientific notation is used for sufficiently small or large numbers.

You don't need to convert this, the *value itself* is a proper float. If you need to display this in a different format, [format it *explicitly*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> print(0.00001357)
1.357e-05
>>> print(format(0.00001357, 'f'))
0.000014
>>> print(format(0.00001357, '.8f'))
0.00001357
```

Here the `f` format *always* uses fixed point notation for the value. The default precision is 6 digits; the `.8` instructs the `f` formatter to show 8 digits instead.

In Python 3, the default string format is essentially the same as `format(fpvalue, '.16g')`; the `g` format uses either a scientific or fixed point presentation depending on the exponent of the number. Python 2 used `'.12g'`.

Comment: not helping since the original values gets changed

Comment: Why not store the value as string?

Comment: ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str' --getting error if i convert a string I tried like
a = '1.00383E+11'
print('{:f}'.format(a))