# Big Number Divide No Power Of

Tags: python

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

def calculator(num1, num2):
\# Set the precision for decimal calculations
getcontext().prec = 39

# Convert the input numbers to Decimal objects
num1 = Decimal(num1)
num2 = Decimal(num2)

# Initialize a variable to store the result
result = num1 / num2

# Perform divisions until the result becomes zero
while result != 0:
    print(result)
    num1 = result
    result = num1 / num2
```

## Example usage

num1 = "131900"
num2 = "2"
calculator(num1, num2)

here is my python code this is big number calculator i want all divide not have power of
for exp: after some step divide my answer
0.0000018466380424797534942626953125

4.61659510619938373565673828125E-7   as you can i want all 39 decimal number without E-7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress scientific notation when printing float values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values)